# Unable to create remote repository when using .xcworkspace Xcode 9 + GitHub

Tags: github, xcode9-beta

I am using Xcode 9 (Beta) which has GitHub integrated into it.

Please note I have pod files (223 MB size !!) in the project, and I've also set up GitHub account in Xcode preferences.

When I don't have any pods installed, I am able to create remote repository on GitHub by opening the `.xcodeproj` file and following the below steps, however it doesn't work when I have pods installed (see below steps).

How could I get around this issue ?

Below are the steps I am following to create a remote repository on GitHub using Xcode 9 (Beta).

**1. Open `.xcworkspace` file**

[image: Project File Structure]

**2. Create Git Repository**

Xcode > Source Control > Create Git Repositories

[image]

**3. Creating remote repository on GitHub**

[image]

[image]

**Result**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Private commits are enabled for paid users only. Try committing with public visibility and it should probably work.